# Multiple threads doesn't work

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, countdownlatch

I am trying to run a code with a GUI interface. But I need the GUI windows all to be closed before I proceed with my main method, (some of the information that I need is collected from the GUI windows and I cant run the rest of my code without that information).
So, I decided to use CountDownLatch to create two threads (one of them being my main method and the other one the class with handles my GUI stuff). But when I run my code it gets stuck at the end of the GUI and it doesn't proceed with my code. does anyone know what is wrong with my code?

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException,InterruptedException{
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        double longThreshold, shortThreshold, investment;
        System.out.println("hello");
        CountDownLatch startSignal = new CountDownLatch(1);
        CountDownLatch stopSignal = new CountDownLatch(1);
        ProgrammeSettings mySettings=new ProgrammeSettings(startSignal,stopSignal);
                new Thread(mySettings).start();  // mysettings object is the GUI stuff
        startSignal.countDown();
            stopSignal.await();
        longThreshold = mySettings.getlowerThreshold();
        shortThreshold = mySettings.getupperThreshold();
        investment =mySettings.getinvestment();
        System.out.println("hello");
}
```

also here is my code for CountDownLatch of the GUI stuff:

```
public class ProgrammeSettings implements Runnable {
private final CountDownLatch startSignal;
private final CountDownLatch stopSignal;

ProgrammeSettings(CountDownLatch startSignal, CountDownLatch doneSignal) {
      this.startSignal = startSignal;
      this.stopSignal = doneSignal;
   }
    public void graphicDesign(){
     // do some GUI stuff 
   }
@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try{
        startSignal.await();
        graphicDesign();
        stopSignal.countDown();
    }
    catch( InterruptedException e){

    }

}
```

}

Comment: You are saying that your code gets stuck in `graphicDesign()`, where you `do some GUI stuff`. It seems you are not showing the part of the code which is relevant to your problem. Do you run that GUI stuff in the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread)?

Comment: You should only be doing GUI stuff on the one GUI event thread. What are you trying to get these threads to do?

Comment: @assylias
no, it doesn't get stuck in graphicDesign(). it gets up to stopSignal.countDown(); and it exits this thread (well that's what I think from running the code in debug mode). but when it gets to stopSignal.await(); it doesn't proceed any further. 
also when I change 
 CountDownLatch stopSignal = new CountDownLatch(  2   );
 to 
 CountDownLatch stopSignal = new CountDownLatch(  1   );

it finishes the code but obviously it doesnt stop until the thread is finished

Comment: @PeterLawrey
I am trying to get some numbers with a gui interface and then use those number to do some calculations. 
I am only using one GUI event thread and thats graphicDesign()

Comment: And you are using `SwingUtils.invokeLater(....)` to update the GUI?

Comment: sorry this is the first time that I am using multiple threads to run something and I am a beginner basically. 
I don't actually know why .invokeLater mathod should be used.

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea does work but you can't run the GUI code in any thread; it must run in Swing's UI thread.

So a better solution is to run your "wait for completion of the data entry" in a new thread and let the main thread handle the UI.

Comment: oh, so I have to check if the data has been collected in say a new class and the do the .countdown for that method in the new class?

Comment: A simple solution would be to use a button which reads "Start" and which calls a method that checks and processes the data.